Webhook signature verification failed. No webhook payload was provided
when i run the following command in the cmd stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded
I get  the following error here is myhandleStripeWebhook
async function handleStripeWebhook(req, res) {
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    // const rawBody = JSON.stringify(req.rawBody);

    try {
        const webhookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;
        if (!webhookSecret) {
            console.log("STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET is not set")
            throw new Error('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET is not set');
        }

        // console.log("Received Stripe webhook:", rawBody);

        // Construct the event using the raw body and signature
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.rawBody, sig, webhookSecret);
        console.log('✅ Webhook signature verified');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.', err.message);
        return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    }

    // Handle the event
    if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
        const session = event.data.object;
        console.log('✅ Checkout session completed event received');
        console.log('Session metadata:', session.metadata);

        // Process the backend logic
        await processBackendLogic(session.metadata);
    }

    res.json({ received: true });
}

and here is my routes :
router.post('/webhook', handleStripeWebhook , bodyParser.json({ verify: function (req, res, buf) { req.rawBody = buf.toString() } }));

I Get the following error
⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed. No webhook payload was provided.


I don't recognize that error, it's possible that it's been updated to be more explicit in a newer version of the library though. Based on the error, I'm wondering if req.rawBody is empty or null? It's also unclear whether you're using the CLI to forward the Event to your endpoint, or just trigger it. If you're using the CLI to forward the Event, you'll also need to use the signing secret that the CLI provides when you run stripe listen rather than the actual secret for the endpoint if it was registered as a webhook endpoint in your Stripe account.

ty for your answer yes indeed I am using CLI to forward the Event and I am using the  signing secret that the CLI provides when i run stripe listen.
I did solve the error

I did solve this error by changing the handleStripeWebhook controller


async function handleStripeWebhook(req, res) {
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    const rawBody = req.rawBody;

    let event;

    try {
        const webhookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;
        if (!webhookSecret) {
            console.log("STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET is not set");
            throw new Error('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET is not set');
        }

        // Construct the event using the raw body and signature
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, sig, webhookSecret);
        console.log('✅ Webhook signature verified');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.', err.message);
        return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    }

    // Handle the event
    if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
        const session = event.data.object;
        console.log('✅ Checkout session completed event received');
        console.log('Session metadata:', session.metadata);

        // Process the backend logic
        await processBackendLogic(session.metadata);
    }

    res.json({ received: true });
}



and also making sure use raw format for the /webhook route


app.use(express.json({
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
      if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/api/webhook')) {
        req.rawBody = buf.toString();
      }
    },
     }));



instead of using


app.use(express.json())



